# show/hide column in datatables plugin in php

Tags: php, datatables, hide, show

I am new in Zend and I am trying to integrate the datatables plugin into my application which is in Zend. I need a function show/Hide column for datatables component.Through google I got some clues but it is not working. My code before integrating the show/hide column is :

```
$('table.datatable').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'firti',
        "iDisplayLength" : -1,
        "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]]
      });
```

It is working without show/hide option. Now I change the code to

```
$('table.datatable').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        "iDisplayLength" : -1,
        "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
        "oColVis": {
            "aiExclude": [ 0 ]
          }
    });
```

But show/hide is not working. Could you please help me how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting any error message ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need explicit define the columns.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({

        "aoColumns": [
                        {"bVisible": false},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true},
                        {"bVisible": true}
                    ]
    }
    );
} );
```

I've created this jsFiddle to make it clear: http://jsfiddle.net/B4SN8/

You also can check datatables.net documentation:
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html